# Unknown column on UPDATE operation

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I created a temporary column in JTable in joomla for some task as below:

```
function __construct(&$db) 
{
    parent::__construct('#__tbl', 'id', $db);

    $id = JRequest::getVar('id');

    if($id!=""){
        //Initialize variables.
        $options = array();

        $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Select some fields
        $query->select('b.fkcategory AS val');

        $query->from('#__tbl AS a');
        $query->join('left', '#__tblb AS b ON a.fkq=b.id');
        $query->where('a.id='.$id);

        // Get the options.
        $db->setQuery($query);

        $row = $db->loadObject();

        $this->fkcategory = $row->val;
    }
```

Now when i save the data i get the error as below:

```
JDatabaseMySQLi::query: 1054 - Unknown column 'fkcategory' in 'field list' 
SQL=UPDATE `cokic_tbl` SET name`='xxx',`gender`='0',`phone`='xxx',
`email`='xxx@test.com',`city`='xxx',`fkcountry`='6',`fkq`='2',`experience`='0',
`cv`='images/banners/osmbanner1.png',`approved`='0',
`registerdate`='2014-08-25 22:43:43',`fkcategory`='2' WHERE `id`='2'
```

It is understood that the error is because of that column ***fkcategory*** which i don't have in the table.

Now I wanna know how can I destroy this column or unset it or do anything which will help me avoid this error. I need to get rid of the column before i go for the save function.

Comment: I think that you need to add a bit more of the code missing (i.e. the dits) in order to help you. The simplest way is to add the missing column off cource.

Comment: If the save is not working it would be really helpful to show the save.  Are you using the base save or have you extended it?  It may work to call it `_fkcategory`.

Comment: @pcrikos, infact I was able to achieve what i wanted, i tried to set the value of a drop down list when the form loaded. So, i did set it in the loadFormData() as $data->set('fkcategory', $row->val). The idea of introducing the column in the JTable was wrong. Anyway thankyou for your time. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it is obvious, that since you do not have the fkcategory field on table #__tblb
the select statemet is going to fire an error.

There are two ways.

add the field fkcategory in table #__tableb

Comment: to complete the answer of @pcrikos, the second way is to drop the added field before you save; just unset($this->fkcategory)